# Is possible configure spring config client uri with eureka service name?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

My project have the next components:

1. Eureka Server [(here repository)](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/eureka-server-v1)
2. Configuration Server [(here repository)](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/config-server-v1)
3. Product-service [(here repository)](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/products-microservice-v1)
4. Github repository with configurations files [(here repository)](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/Config-repository-v1)

The idea is that product-service component will be registered on eureka server on start-up, it will find where is the ip address of config server and then download product-service.properties from git. Example of start-up with errors [here](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/products-microservice-v1/blob/main/log2).

*Github links below show all configurations but there is a sumary*

**Eureka Server properties**

```
server.port=8761
  
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

**Config Server properties**

```
#Application
spring.application.name=configservice
server.port=8888

#Eureka client
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
#Disable DNS
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true

#Configuration server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/Config-repository-v1
```

**Product-service microservice**

```
spring.cloud.name=product-service
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.profile=development
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=configservice
```

But if I register product-service component on eureka and configure to takes product-service-development.properties directly from configserver without using eureka server it runns correctly.

```
spring.application.name=product-service
spring.config.import=configserver:http://localhost:8888
spring.profiles.include=development
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true 
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Example of start-up without errors [here](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/products-microservice-v1/blob/main/log1).

I couldn't find some configuration in order to my product-service download product-service.properties asking to eureka server where is the configuration file. Configuration is reachable and config server is registered in eureka server:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/product-service/development/

{"name":"product-service","profiles":["development"],"label":null,"version":"7dc446ca4d1d1bb2b024179b240b760018862f4c","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/Config-repository-v1/product-service-development.properties","source":{"server.port":"8081","spring.datasource.url":"jdbc:h2:mem:testdb","spring.datasource.driverClassName":"org.h2.Driver","spring.datasource.username":"sa","spring.datasource.password":"password","spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization":"true","spring.jpa.database-platform":"org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect","spring.h2.console.enabled":"true","spring.h2.console.path":"/h2-console","spring.h2.console.settings.trace":"false","spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others":"false","spring.application.name":"PRODUCT-SERVICE","eureka.client.service-url.default-zone":"http://localhost:8761/eureka","eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address":"true","management.endpoints.web.exposure.include":"*","management.info.env.enabled":"true","info.app.name":"PRODUCT-SERVICE","info.app.version":"1.0.0","info.app.description":"Microservice which allow us to manage products","info.author":""}},{"name":"https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/Config-repository-v1/application.properties","source":{"sample.property":"sample"}}]}
```

[image]

May be spring client config is impossible to download configuration properties using finding on eureka server which is the ip address of spring cloud server? Reading [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/) seems that is possible but I can't configure or find some similiar configuration over internet.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved.**

In fact, application.properties of products-service was incorrect. Here the properly configuration:

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true

spring.cloud.config.name=product-service
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=configservice
spring.cloud.config.profile=development
```